# Why variable declared via let a=5 gives undefined output if we call this.a?

Tags: javascript

```
let a=5;
var b=6;

console.log(this.a); //why we get undefined if we run this in global context.
console.log(this.b); //output:6
```

**`let a=5;` why we get undefined if we `console.log(this.a);`**

Comment: [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let): _"At the top level of programs and functions, **`let`**, unlike `var`, **does not create a property on the global object**"_

Comment: Unlike `let`, variable with `var` is added on the global window object.

Comment: The [documentation for `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) explains the differences.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN Web Docs:

> "unlike the var keyword, which declares a variable globally, or
> locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. The other
> difference between var and let is that the latter is initialized to a
> value only when a parser evaluates it"

Can read more about it here: [MDN - let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)